# Instantly transfer a picture taken to PC

Tags: applications, sync, dropbox

I know the Dropbox app allows for synching photos taken between all computers/devices that are connected to your current user account. But I want to know if there's a way I can take a picture, have it delivered to my PC (Dropbox account) and then instantly deleted from my device (kinda like a cut/paste action).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) app (it is a paid app).

The app allows you to setup local folder(s) on your device which can be synced to various cloud services, a shared folder, or even FTP (see below for a full list). When setting up a "folder pair" you can choose to "delete source files after sync".

There is also a [lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) version available if you want to test it out first.

Full list of supported cloud services/protocols:

```
Cloud providers
- Amazon S3 Simple Storage Service
- Box
- CloudMe (using WebDAV)
- Copy.com
- Cubby (using WebDAV)
- Digitalbucket.net (using WebDAV)
- Dropbox
- Dump Truck (using WebDAV)
- GoDaddy (using WebDAV)
- Google Docs
- Google Drive
- HiDrive (using WebDAV)
- Livedrive (using WebDAV)
- MyDrive.ch (using WebDAV)
- NetDocuments (using WebDAV)
- Skydrive
- SugarSync
- Ubuntu One
- WEB.DE (using WebDAV)
- Yandex Disk (using WebDAV)

Supported protocols
- FTP
- FTPS (SSL/TLS implicit)
- FTPES (SSL/TLS explicit)
- SFTP (SSH File Transfer)
- Samba/CIFS/Windows Share
- WebDAV (HTTP/HTTPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called Silent Sifter on our Mac desktop. I think it was like $9 or something but it was very worth it.  Upon initial set up, it got rid of all my duplicates and filed all my existing scattered photos by year and month within that.

What I love about it is that you tell it what folders you want to "input" (Dropbox folder, whatever...) and then where you want it to "output" (I created a folder simply called "Photos - Master").  Then you can tell it how you would like the files to be named and organized (subfolders).  You can then set it to automatically scan and sift as any changes are made.

What this means for me is that anytime I take a photo on my Note 3, it is automatically synced to Dropbox (because I set it up that way in Dropbox).  Then Silent Sifter kicks in on my computer after seeing a change has been made within the Dropbox folder.  It will look at the EXIF data on the photo and I have it set to sort by Year > Month (because I do Project Life style scrapbooking).  You can go as far as sorting by Year > Month > Day > Moment.  I NEVER have to touch a cord again!  So glad I found this program! Especially because Macs are IGNORANT with Android phones...don't even recognize them being connected without additional software - such a P.I.T.A.

I'm sure it can do more than I have even figured out with it yet - I'm not super tech savvy but I try!

Comment: Two questions: 1) maybe you've got a link on where to find that program? 2) does it meet the OPs requirement of "moving" the pic (not just copying it, but also removing it from the device)?